# Use percentile_cont with a "group by" statment in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'd like to use the `percentile_cont` function to get median values in T-SQL. However, I also need to get mean values as well. I'd like to do something like the following:

```
SELECT  CustomerID ,
    AVG(Expenditure) AS MeanSpend , percentile_cont
    ( .5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Expenditure) OVER( ) AS MedianSpend
FROM    Customers
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Can this be accomplished? I know I can use the OVER clause to group the `percentile_cont` results...

but then I'm stuck using two queries, am I not?

Comment: Have you tried it?  I think that this does work.

Comment: I have tried it. Here's the error...

Column 'Expenditure' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just figured it out... gotta drop the group by and give both aggregation functions a over statement.

```
SELECT CustomerID,
    AVG(Expenditure) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID) AS MeanSpend,
    percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Expenditure) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID) AS MedianSpend
FROM Customers
```

Comment: If you have more than one row in your group, it will return duplicates. And if you only have one row per group, then you don't need any of these functions.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use "group by" with window functions. These functions return the aggregated values for every row. One way is to use "select distinct" to get rid of the duplicate rows. Just make sure you partition each window function by the non-aggregated columns (groupId in this example).

```
--Generate test data
SELECT  TOP(10) 
    value.number%3  AS  groupId
,   value.number    AS  number
INTO    #data
FROM  master.dbo.spt_values  AS  value
WHERE value."type" = 'P' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
;

--View test data
SELECT  * FROM #data ORDER BY groupId,number;

--CALCULATE MEDIAN
SELECT DISTINCT 
    groupId
,   AVG(number)                                         OVER(PARTITION BY groupId)  AS mean
,   percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY number)   OVER(PARTITION BY groupId)  AS median
FROM    #data
;

--Clean up
DROP TABLE #data;
```