# SQL Server: PERCENTILE_DISC for column median without partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm trying to run `PERCENTILE_DISC` on a column of values in a table to get their median. I notice that the function has a mandatory partition clause and I'm wondering if there's a way to not use it. I am interested only in the median of the entire column, not subsets of its values by some other categorical. I even tried this hack to try to get the median of `my_value`:

```
SELECT
    PERCENTILE_DISC (0.5)
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_value) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
FROM
    my_table
```

But just got a vector of 1s the length of my table. Is there a way to just get a column median without partitioning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The normal way is to use:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_value) OVER ()
FROM my_table;
```

If you want only one row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY my_value) OVER ()
FROM my_table;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not offer this as an aggregation function.

Comment: if you want to also include an 'mean' average you can use this format `AVG(Expenditure) OVER() AS MeanSpend` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546991/16940)